# how can i do Limit the file app size in ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to write a app to download and manage files from the web.  If I just put the file in the Document. Is there any limit of file size in the Directory?

can any one help me..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning with the introduction of iOS5 saving large files or files that can be regenerated into the documents directory is frowned upon (actually you were never meant to do it but its only being enforced now). This is because the files in the documents directory get backed up to iCloud and you obviously do not want to fill that up. Apple have started rejecting apps just for this reason.

You should now place the downloaded files into the temp or cache directories. But also be aware that the OS will clear these directories when running low on memory so you need to have logic in you app to check if the files exist and re-download if they do not.

Answer (score 0):

No real limit except the device and other user data. Still best to be frugal.